# Matlab's TriScatteredInterp implementation in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, point-cloud-library

I have x,y,z 3D points in the array size of N x 3 dimensions. As they are scattered data points, I need to match into equally spaced grid data. The implementation in Matlab used TriScatteredInterp as shown in the [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triscatteredinterp.html). I need to implement it in C++ and plot the data and save as png file. So I searched and found out that I should implement in PCL library. As I am not familiar with PCL, how can I approach that problem using PCL? Can I have any sample program?
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked for [implementations](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/delaunay2.cpp) of the [Delaunay triangulation in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446987/lightweight-delaunay-trianguation-library-for-c)?

Comment: Delaunay triangulation I know. How to do interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your exact needs for the equaly spaced grid data. When looking at the matlab function I believe you would like to do the following:

**1) Perform surface reconstruction on the scattered data points**
In PCL you should be able to do this according to example:
[Greedy Triangulation tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/greedy_projection.php)

**2) Show the surface in a viewer**
This step could be realized by using the VTK viewer. An example is shonw in:
[VTK mesh viewing](http://www.pcl-users.org/vtk-visualization-td3770545.html)

**3) Save the image of the viewer as a PNG file.**
The last step could be realized using the VTKviewer also. An example can be found:
[VTKviewer save as PNG example](http://www.pcl-users.org/saveScreenshot-not-working-td3373391.html)

Comment: Many thanks I need that kind of suggestion.

Comment: Matlab do Delaunay triangulation.  Then then with those point, linear interpolation is done.

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand how TriScatteredInterp works in Matlab.

We have x,y,z points for N X 3 dimensions. All these points, we need to implement Delaunay triangles in C++. That is easy.

Then, for all your desired grid points x', y', please search the triangle in which your x',y' is located. Then do Barycentric interpolation in a triangle as shown in the [link](http://cumbia.visus.uni-stuttgart.de/ger/research/proj/ito/materials/VIS-Slides-03-Interpolation_and_Filtering.pdf). You will get z' for these x',y'.

That is all what we need to do in C++ for TriScatteredInterp.

You will get a matrix of x',y',z', then I follow @Deepfreeze's idea for plotting using PCL. We can also use OpenGl for plotting.

It doesn't stop at Delaunay triangulation, still need to do interpolation.